How to do a weighted median test for two samples in R?
I have two samples (Group 1 and Group 2), each containing 1) an income variable and 2) a weight variable indicating the weight for each observation.
I simply want to test whether the medians of income in the two samples (Group 1 and Group 2) are statistically different.
I know I can use Mood's median test if I don't consider the weights, but is there a way to perform the median test while accounting for the weights of each observation?
Thanks for your help in advance!

survey:svyranktest will do this for you. It has an option test="median" to compare medians.
